# Facing issue while rounidng up a value in python

Tags: python, math, ceil

I have following code

```
import math

a = (4, 31)
b = (0, 29)
c = (1, 31)

print(int(math.ceil(sum(a) / 7)))
print(int(math.ceil(sum(b) / 7)))
print(int(math.ceil(sum(c) / 7)))
```

I am getting output as 5,4,4

Ideally I should get 5, 5, 5

I am not sure whats going on here. If try the same in python console, I get output as expected (5,5,5) but in python If I write a program and execute it, I get 5,4,4.

Comment: It works fine for me, without any changes.

Comment: This depends on python 2 vs 3. Just do `import sys; print(sys.version)` in both of your environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dividing by an `integer`, when you want to divide by a `float`. Use `/7.` instead of `/7`:

```
import math

a = (4, 31)
b = (0, 29)
c = (1, 31)

print(int(math.ceil(sum(a) / 7.)))
print(int(math.ceil(sum(b) / 7.)))
print(int(math.ceil(sum(c) / 7.)))
```

**Output**

```
5
5
5
```

Comment: This Solves my issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

My guess is that you're executing some version of Python 2 when you run it as a program, but some version of Python 3 "in the Python console".  `/` applied to integers behaves differently between Pythons 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 is implicitely converting (truncating) your floating point intermediate result to the next lower integer. So you get

```
   sum((0,29))/7
   => 4
```

If you want to have the a floating point result, you need to have any operand be a float:

```
   sum((0,29))/7.0
   => 4.1428571428571432
```

Or you cast one of the operands to a float like this:

```
   sum((0,29))/float(7)
   => 4.1428571428571432
```

Then your code will also work in python2. Python3 already uses floating point intermediate result, so the same code looks like this in p3:

```
   sum((0,29))/7
   => 4.1428571428571432
   sum((0,29))/7.0
   => 4.1428571428571432
```

For details see this article: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1439189